# Create page when add new category in woocammerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create new page automatically when I add new category in **WooCommerce**. And new page slug is same with new category .

**So my code is :**

```
function programmatically_create_post() {

$author_id = 1;
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$orderby = 'name';
$show_count = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title = '';
$empty = 0;

$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'show_count' => $show_count,
    'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'title_li' => $title,
    'hide_empty' => $empty
);

$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
$lastCategory=$all_categories[0];
$slug =$lastCategory->slug;
$title=$lastCategory->name;
// If the page doesn't already exist, then create it

if( null == get_page_by_title( $title ) ) {

// Set the post ID so that we know the post was created successfully

$post_id = wp_insert_post(

  array(

   'post_author'   => $author_id,
    'post_name'   => $slug,
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'page',
      'post_slug'=> $slug

  )

);



// Otherwise, we'll stop

} else {

    // Arbitrarily use -2 to indicate that the page with the title already exists

    $post_id = -2;

} // end if
} // end programmatically_create_post


add_action('create_product_cat', 'programmatically_create_post', 10, 1);
```

I think get last category of database ,but it is wrong.I very googling but I cant find my problem.

How can I get new category slug when I add new category ?

Have any beast way to add new page with same slug of new category?

Comment: `add_action('create_product_cat', 'programmatically_create_post', 10, 2);`  try this. Just put 2 instead one at the end.

Comment: @MD. Atiqur Rahman thanks it fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole code is fine but you have just a little priority problem. Now, you just need to change the priority from 1 to 2.

`add_action('create_product_cat', 'programmatically_create_post', 10, 2);`

That should work!

Comment: could you give me create_product_cat tutorial's url ?

Comment: I'd recommend the WordPress codex. Learn the hooks and how to do filtering.